# How to get kobject from current module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

In Linux kernel, given a module how can I know is it's kobject?

Context:
I am trying to do a sysfs_create_file(kobj,attr) in a kernel module. I have all the attribute stuff set up, but I want to add an attribute to the current module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok after looking through module.h I found it.

```
struct kobject mod_kobj = (((struct module *)(THIS_MODULE))->mkobj).kobj;
```